# Opening and communicating with a subprocess

Tags: python, process

I have a subprocess that I use. I must be able to asynchronously read and write to/from this process to it's respective stdout and stdin.

How can I do this? I have looked at `subprocess`, but the `communicate` method waits for process termination (which is not what I want) and the `subprocess.stdout.read` method can block.

The subprocess is **not** a Python script but can be edited if absolutely necessary. In total I will have around 15 of these subprocesses.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look how `communicate` is implemented.

There are essentially 2 ways to do it:

1. either use `select()` and be notified whether you can read/write,
2. or delegate the read and write, which both can block, to a thread, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using some queue or NOSQL DB for inter process communication?
I would suggest you to use Redis, and read and write to different keys with your processes.

Answer (score 0):

Have  a look at sarge: http://sarge.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

From the sarge docs:

If you want to interact with external programs from your Python applications, Sarge is a library which is intended to make your life easier than using the subprocess module in Python’s standard library.